# mongoDB: getMongo() on a db instance returns error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to do a sql transaction. for this I need to start a session which a possible only with a mongo dB connection instance.

In my app, I can reach only the DB instance. and I need to be able to get from it the mongodb connection instance. As I understand, [getMongo()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getMongo/) function should do exactly that.

The problem is the getMongo() is not acting as expected.

when i run this following code:

```
  const db = await this.dbClient;
  console.log(db,"db");
  console.log(db.getMongo(),"getMongo");

  const session  = db.getMongo().startSession();
```

I get this following console.log and errors:

```
    Db {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  s: {
    dbCache: {},
    children: [],
    topology: NativeTopology {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 35,
      _maxListeners: Infinity,
      s: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(waitQueue)]: [Denque]
    },
    options: {
      retryWrites: true,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise]
    },
    logger: Logger { className: 'Db' },
    bson: BSON {},
    readPreference: ReadPreference { mode: 'primary', tags: undefined },
    bufferMaxEntries: -1,
    parentDb: null,
    pkFactory: undefined,
    nativeParser: undefined,
    promiseLibrary: [Function: Promise],
    noListener: false,
    readConcern: undefined,
    writeConcern: undefined,
    namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'MyDB', collection: undefined }
  },
  serverConfig: [Getter],
  bufferMaxEntries: [Getter],
  databaseName: [Getter],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
} db
{"Error msg: TypeError: db.getMongo is not a 
function\n...","level":"error"}
{"session is not defined....","level":"error"}
```

Anybody knows what it the problem?
My mongo version is 4.2.6.
Many thanks

Comment: Are you using [`node-mongodb-native`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)? If so you should consult the documentation accordingly https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Db.html there is no db.getMongo() method